# ssh: Could not resolve hostname (name of server): No address associated with hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, server

I have server A which connects with multiple remote servers and transfers the files from there to a target directory on server A. I have the following code to connect with the servers and check if the file exists or not. Depending on that, the script will either transfer the file or print a "File not found statement".

```
 if ssh -n user@${server};
    then
      printf "We are in -- $server --\n"
      if ssh -n user@${server} test -e $SOURCEFILE;
        then
          printf "File found in -- $server --\n\n"
          #command to transfer the files
      else
        printf "File not found in -- $server --\n\n"
      fi
  else
    printf "Unable to access -- $server --\n\n"
  fi
```

However, the output shows me that the ssh connection is unsuccessful between the server A and the remote server and this happens randomly. For example, if I run the script today, it might give me an error for server B, tomorrow server B will be working fine and it might give me the error for server C.
I have tried deleting the hostkeys and creating them again but that didn't work. I am confused why this happens randomly for each server.
Any insight into this would be really helpful.

Comment: The error message indicates that it's having trouble resolving the server name. So this is a DNS problem.

Comment: Do you any suggestions on how to fix it? @Barmar

Comment: You need to talk to your DNS administrator to find out why the names aren't resolving reliably. Possibly a problem with replication to the backup nameservers.

Comment: The dns administrator says its all good since the nslookup command gives the expected response. If you have any other suggestions to transfer the files without having to go through the ssh route, I'm open to those as well.